# Un mot pour décrire des passions passagères

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Existe-t-il un mot pour décrire une personne qui s’adonne à de nombreuses passions (ou activités / hobby / sujets d’études) passagers et qui en change souvent.

Existe-t-il aussi un mot pour décrire ce genre d’activités, j’ai trouvé le mot «lubie» mais selon le wikitionnaire (https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lubie) il s’agit plutôt de caprices que de passions, ce n’est pas exactement le sens que je recherche.

Comment: @ben Comme il y a en fait deux questions: la personne et l'occupation, vous pourriez ouvrir deux postes différents, car cela nécessite deux réponses.

Comment: À double question, double réponse : http://french.stackexchange.com/a/13929/1514 . @YohannV.: Je ne suis pas d'accord avec "lubie", comme d'ailleurs Ben l'indique parfaitement.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Pour moi, une lubie peut avoir le sens de passion, selon le sens que l'on donne à passion. Mais si effectivement ce n'est pas ce que Ben recherche, je supprime mon commentaire.

Comment: La question est vraiment difficile car une passion est habituellement considéré comme quelque chose de pérenne. Une passion passagère est donc généralement considérée négativement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pour la **personne**, on parle d'un [**dilettante**](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dilettante)¹, c'est-à-dire quelqu'un de [*versatile*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/versatile)².

Pour l'**activité**, on peut dire [*fantaisies*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fantaisie) (au sens d'*humeur, désir*), et j'utilise personnellement « [passions courtes](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/passion) », qui a surtout le mérite de la clarté.

---

Globalement, le comportement que tu décris est mal vu par la langue française, et beaucoup mieux connoté en anglais. Par exemple…

- l'[*amateur*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/amateurisme) (négligent) est dénigré par rapport au *professionnel* (qualifié, établi, respectable)
- *lubie* pourrait bien décrire l'activité en question, si ça n'était pas synonyme de *caprice* (mal connoté encore une fois)
- *fantaisiste* signifie souvent « qui ne doit pas être pris trop au sérieux ».
  Dans [le dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/fantaisiste) :

  > Employé comme nom, il se dit de Celui, de celle qui n'obéit guère qu'aux caprices de sa fantaisie.

  On appréciera le dédain.

---

<sub>¹ merci [P. Obertelli](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13897/1514)</sub>
<sub>² qui évoque la méfiance, au lieu de forcer l'admiration comme en anglais. Pour en dire du bien, on utilise plutôt *polyvalent*.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

D'après le TLFi, « lubie » me semble convenir :

> Idée extravagante, déraisonnable ou capricieuse, généralement soudaine et passagère. Synon. caprice, fantaisie, folie, toquade (fam.).Lubie d'enfant gâté, de pochard. Bonaparte n'est plus le vrai Bonaparte, c'est une figure légendaire composée des lubies du poète, des devis du soldat et des contes du peuple (Chateaubr., Mém.,t. 2, 1848, p. 652).Elle a répété dix fois, vingt fois, qu'elle voulait entrer au couvent (...). Que pensez-vous de cette nouvelle lubie? (Zola, Fécondité,1899, p. 414).Madame a renoncé à sa voiture : c'est sa dernière lubie (Mauriac, Désert am.,1925, p. 68):
>   Quelquefois des lubies le prennent tout à coup et il les attribue au ver solitaire : « Il veut cela » et de suite Louis obéit. Dernièrement il a voulu manger pour trente sols de brioche... Flaub., Corresp.,1853, p. 152.

Pour parler de centres d'intérêt changeant.
S'il s'agit au contraire d'une passion vers laquelle on revient sans cesse, « dada » pourrait très bien aller :

> Au fig., p. métaph. Sujet favori; idée ou occupation à laquelle on revient sans cesse. Avoir un nouveau dada; le dada favori de qqn; avoir un dada; c'est son dada. Synon. manie, marotte, toquade.Chaque Anglais a sa manie propre, son dada, son hobby (Morand, Londres,1933, p. 78).Toujours des nouveaux caprices! Des nouveaux dadas! (Céline, Mort à crédit,1936, p. 641):
>   2. Un homme qui n'a pas de dada ignore tout le parti qu'on peut tirer de la vie. Un dada est le milieu précis entre la passion et la monomanie. Balzac, Autre étude de femme,1842, p. 411.
>   − [Accompagné d'autres termes fig. du même champ sém.] Pourvu qu'elle n'enfourche pas son dada socialiste (Flaub., Corresp.,1866, p. 246).M. de Flagny suivait pour l'ordinaire mes galops d'amour au petit trot de son dada de la fraternité (Milosz, Amour. initiation,1910, p. 222).À cheval sur tous les grands dadas de l'entre-trois-guerres (H. Bazin, Vipère,1948, p. 18).

Comment: Si je comprends bien la question, les connotations qui vont avec *lubie* ne sont pas du tout ce que le questionneur recherche, donc le mot convient mal (décrit la bonne chose, mais pas comme il faut). *Dada* est sans rapport avec la question (c'est le contraire).

Answer (score 4):

Le mot pour décrire la personne pourrait être "Dilettante" (Larrousse)

> Personne qui s'adonne à une occupation, à un art en amateur, pour son
> seul plaisir.
>
> **Personne qui ne suit que les impulsions de son plaisir, de ses goûts, qui exerce une activité de manière fantaisiste** : Vivre en
> dilettante.

L'activité correspondante est le ["dilettantisme"](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dilettantisme)

> Attitude d'une personne exerçant une activité comme un passe-temps,
> généralement de façon fantaisiste.
>
> ...un dilettantisme de décorateur.../...livres de dilettantisme philosophique .../...un dilettantisme professionnel.../... Un dilettantisme à moitié ironique.../...le dilettantisme de la jeunesse parisienne.

Ou sinon, dans un registre un peu plus familier, mais qui correspond exactement à la définition recherchée:

Un "Touche-à-tout"

> Qui a l'habitude de toucher à tout.
> **Qui s'occupe de tout, aborde tous les domaines, mais superficiellement.**

L'activité correspondante est avoir des "passe-temps"(cnrtl)

> Activité, occupation légère, distrayante ou studieuse que l'on se
> donne pour passer le temps, pour éviter de s'ennuyer.

On peut aussi parler, suivant le degré de passion exercée sur ces activités secondaires: de hobbies, dada ou violon d’Ingres.

Comment: Et pour l'activité ? :P Le problème, c'est qu'on cherche un mot pour désigner quelque chose qui change souvent. +1, ces expressions désignent bien ce que cherche le questionneur. [J'emprunte](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/13929/1514)…

Comment: @Nikana Reklawyks ce sont des passe-temps ou hobbies, j'ai édité mon poste.

Answer (score 2):

Le verbe «papillonner» d'une chose à l' autre, d'une personne à l' autre, d'une activité à l'autre, convient bien pour décrire ce genre de personnalité.

Exemple:

«Voilà deux ans qu'elle papillonne d'un hobby à l'autre, sans vraiment savoir lequel choisir».

Answer (score 1):

Pour l’idée d’une personne qui change souvent, il y a « [une girouette](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/girouette) » :

> B. − Au fig. Personne versatile, qui change fréquemment d'opinion.
>
> − Emploi à valeur d'adj. Tu n'écriras pas tes mémoires. Trop
>   paresseux, trop girouette pour cela. **Une lubie** chasse l'autre (Arnoux,
>   Roi,1956, p. 83).

(pour le voir utilisé en locution avec “une lubie” [la bonne réponse de Toto])

« [Pirouette](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pirouette) » aussi a ce sens figuratif de changer (brusquement, mais pas forcément souvent et c’est pour ça que je préfère « girouette » :

> 2. Au fig.  a) Changement brusque d'opinion, de comportement. Synon. revirement, volte-face.Cocteau avait réussi assez de pirouettes pour
>      ne pas toucher un sol pollué et voici que L'Espoir de Malraux (...)
>      éclatait sur l'écran (Vialar,Tournez, 1956, p.220).